# How can I store an optional numerical value in an avro schema

Tags: java, null, resultset, long-integer, avro

I'm writing some code that stores a Java ResultSet as AVRO data/schema.  I'm pretty new to AVRO.

The way I'm doing this is I take the ResultSet and I query its ColumnMetadata to generate the AVRO schema.  Here I convert from Oracle types to AVRO types.  For example, I turn VARCHAR to STRING and NUMBER to LONG.

Then I take the data from the ResultSet and write it out as a TSV file so we have a human-readable version of the output for diagnostic purposes.  Then I iterate over what's in the TSV file and write it out as an AVRO file using DatumWriter/DataFileWriter.

The problem I'm having is that some of the (Oracle) tables I'm querying have nullable NUMBER columns.  In cases where this column is null, it is "" when I read it from the TSV file.  If I try to write "" to a LONG field, the DataFileWriter chokes with this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter$AppendWriteException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

Since the message here indicates that the DataFileWriter is using java.lang.Long (as opposed to a primitive long) I assumed that I could just detect cases where the Field is a LONG and the value is "" and set the value explicitly to null.

When I try to serialize this, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter$AppendWriteException: java.lang.NullPointerException: null of long in field COLUMN_NAME of NAMESPACE.NAME
```

Now this exception refers to primitive long instead of java.lang.Long.

What am I missing here?  Is it possible to have an AVRO field that is an optional LONG?

I've considered not writing the TSV file and instead just writing the AVRO file directly from what I see in the ResultSet, but I have a hunch I'm going to have the same problem since the DataFileWriter doesn't seem to like "" or null values for LONG fields.  I suppose I could just make everything a STRING field, but I'd prefer to retain the column type so sorting and whatnot work properly downstream.

Comment: OK the first exception (String cannot be cast to Long) is because of a bug on my part.  I was reading text from the TSV file and storing it as a String and using that String in GenericData.Record.put().  Now I'm reading the data from the file as Object which I think is better but I still have the NullPointerException.

I've seen plenty of AVRO examples that refer to numeric columns with default value of null, so I don't think what I'm doing is off the chart.